# Automatic Query result in Entity-Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework

I have a database with lots of tables connected with a foreign keys. I use Entity Framework 6 with .NET 4.5 in Visual Studio.

I wanted to know if Entity Framework has an option to automatically return results by querying the main table for its ID and return all the results in JSON from all the connected tables including the main table. Is such option exists, considering that I need to query only based on the main table ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about Lazy Loading.  I believe it is enable by default and you can check this example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it, and I thought I was asking a stupid question and afraid of people calling me lazy (lol, hence the name)

Comment: I think lazy loading is not what I am looking for, because I don't want the related objects to be retrieved when I access the property. I think that eager loading is close to what I need, but what I am searching for is a way to let EF to call all related objects automatically, without me needing to specify any path (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896272(v=vs.100).aspx)